# Extract email addresses from text file using regex with bash or command line

Tags: regex, linux, bash

How can I grep out only the email address using a regex from a file with multiple lines similar to this.  (a sql dump to be precise)

Unfortunately I cannot just go back and dump the email column at this point.

Example data:

```
62372,35896,1,cgreen,Chad,Green,cgreen@blah.com,123456789,0,,,,,,,,,3,Blah,,2013-05-02 17:42:31.659574,164842,,0,0
```

I have tried this but it did not work:

```
grep -o '[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}' file.csv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the field position then it is much easier with awk or cut:

```
awk -F ',' '{print $7}' file
```

OR

```
cut -d ',' -f7 file
```

Comment: This answer, of course, assume there are no escaped commas anywhere in the file.  Comas are permitted in email addresses, so something like `foo\,bar@gmail.com` could, in theory, exist.

Comment: @Flimzy: Agreed, CSV can be pretty complicated and shell tools are not best for parsing it.

Answer (score 50):

If you still want to go the `grep -o` route, this one works for me:

```
$ grep -i -o '[A-Z0-9._%+-]\+@[A-Z0-9.-]\+\.[A-Z]\{2,4\}' file.csv
cgreen@blah.com
$
```

I appear to have 2 versions of grep in my path, 2.4.2 and 2.5.1.  Only 2.5.1 appears to support the -o option.

Your regular expression is close, but you're missing 2 things:

- regular expressions are case sensitive.  So you can either pass `-i` to grep or add extra `a-z` to your square bracket expressions
- The `+` modifiers and `{}` curly braces appear to need to be escaped.

Comment: This is the best answer because it's not specific to csv files (and neither is the title of the question, so most people who see this page will not have this constraint). If anyone wants to find only the unique emails, this would be the way: 
`grep -i -o '[A-Z0-9._%+-]\+@[A-Z0-9.-]\+\.[A-Z]\{2,4\}' file.csv | sort --unique`

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this is with a proper CSV parser.  A simple way to accomplish that, if it's a one-time task, is to load the CSV file into your favorite spreadsheet software, then extract just the email field.

It is difficult to parse CSV with a regex, because of the possibility of escaped commas, quoted text, etc.

Consider, the following are valid email addresses, according to Internet standards:

- foo,bar@gmail.com
- foo"bar@gmail.com

If you know for a fact that you will never have this sort of data, then perhaps simple grep and awk tools will work (as in @anubhava's answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it using [python](/questions/tagged/python) with the help of the built-in `csv` module and the external `validators` module, like this:

```
import validators
import csv
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1], newline='') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        for field in row:
            if validators.email(field):
                print(field)
```

Run it like:

```
python3 script.py infile
```

That yields:

```
cgreen@blah.com
```

Comment: csv is built in, but validators is not - `import validators` fails (for me) in Python 2.7.

Comment: @shacker: True. You must install it first.